# Artinian integral domains are fields.

Tags: ring-theory

I was thinking about the question above and can't find an easy way of proving it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it seems a little advanced and don't get your point. It would be nice to have a more detailed answer. Anyways I did it proving that under those hypothesis the ring can't have proper ideals so it has to be a field.

Comment: As the duplicate says, prime ideals are maximal in artinian rings. If zero is prime in the artinian ring, it is maximal. But zero is maximal iff it is a field.  So this is a very special case. A couple solutions even describe a solution to this problem.

Comment: Also, please review [the guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for question quality and take them to heart.  If your question had not been a duplicate, it would probably have been quickly closed pending improvement.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was very probable that the question was answered but couldn't find it, or in case I saw it, wasn't clear for me that the question you have indicated contained the answer I was looking for. Will look harder next time.

Comment: Self-contained proof: Let $0\ne r\in R$. The $(r^n)$ forming a decreasing sequence of ideals, we have $(r^{n+1})=(r^n)$ for some $n$, that is, $r^n=r^{n+1}s$ for some $s\in R$. As $r^n\ne0$, this implies $1=rs$, showing that $r$ in invertible. (I think this is the standard proof.) (@Joss Please use the `@` sign if you want users to be notified.) (I deleted my previous comment because it was silly.)

Comment: @Joss Finally, if you're going to say you thought about a problem, you should back it up with what you started with and continued through. If you are just going to say "I thought about it but couldn't solve it." and nothing else, you haven't thought about it enough, and there's a chance your question will be closed until you supply *something* forthcoming.

Comment: Excuse me @rschwieb, but who do you think you are to tell me how long I have to think about a question before  asking? I already apologized for not finding in a previous post the answer to a different question which leads to the one I had. I also encourage you to review the guidelines because I thought this site was about questions and answers, not to go on and on about question formatting or other math unrelated topics. Anyways, I will continue asking my questions in a space I still think is about math and cooperation. Thank you once more.

Comment: @Joss *how long* Long enough to produce something substantive to add to the post. What you write may be on the wrong track, but it's helpful for answerers to know what track you are on.  I'm very familiar with the guidelines and how they apply, thank you.  What I said was purely in the interest of helping your question stay afloat. If you are not interested in successfully asking questions then by all means you may ignore me.